# Symfony3 querybuilder orderby count few manytomany

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, symfony

I have an entity called Tag, it has 3 ManyToMany relations fests, articles and news.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Tag:
    type: entity
    table: tag
    ...
  manyToMany:
      news:
          orderBy: { 'posted': 'DESC' }
          targetEntity: News
          inversedBy: tags
          joinTable:
            name: news_tag
            joinColumns:
              tag_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
              news_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
      articles:
          orderBy: { 'posted': 'DESC' }
          targetEntity: Article
          inversedBy: tags
          joinTable:
            name: article_tag
            joinColumns:
              tag_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
              article_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
      fests:
          orderBy: { 'when_starts': 'DESC', 'when_ends': 'DESC' }
          targetEntity: Fest
          inversedBy: tags
          joinTable:
            name: fest_tag
            joinColumns:
              tag_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
              fest_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Now I want to write a createQueryBuilder that orders by the count "news" + count "articles" + count "fests", just for finding "TOP TAGS". I found solution only for one manyToMany relation.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:
What I have:

```
    $qb->select(array(
        't.id', 
        't.name', 
        'COUNT(f) as festcount',
        'COUNT(n) as newscount',
        'COUNT(a) as articlescount',
        '(COUNT(f) + COUNT(n) + COUNT(a)) as totalcount'
        ))
    ->from('AppBundle:Tag', 't')
    ->leftJoin('t.fests', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('t.articles', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('t.news', 'n')
    ->groupBy('t.id')
    ->orderBy('totalcount', 'DESC');
```

But it giving fake results. When some tag has 3 fests, 1 article and 0 news, result is festcount = 3, newscount = 0, articlescount = 3 and totalcount = 6, and it should be 4.

Comment: Post is missing code which you want to achieve.

Comment: @michail_w thanks for comment, I wrote that i need to 'build' createQueryBuilder that will select tags ordered by sum of counts of all relations (news+articles+fests) DESC.

Comment: The rule of StackOverflow is to help people with their problems, not to do their job. Nobody would answer this question until you post code of queryBuilder that you already have.

Comment: @michail_w i updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$qb->select(array(
        't.id', 
        't.name', 
        'COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) as festcount',
        'COUNT(DISTINCT n.id) as newscount',
        'COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) as articlescount',
        '(festcount + newscount + articlescount) as totalcount'
        ))
    ->from('AppBundle:Tag', 't')
    ->leftJoin('t.fests', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('t.articles', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('t.news', 'n')
    ->groupBy('t.id')
    ->orderBy('totalcount', 'DESC');
```

If you'll need further help, please provide dump of those tables.

Comment: WOW! I dont know why, but it works. BTW. this line: `'(festcount + newscount + articlescount) as totalcount'` i need to write as: `(COUNT(DISTINCT f) + COUNT(DISTINCT n) + COUNT(DISTINCT a)) as totalcount` because im gettin error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr_2' in 'field list'`